# JDFPrintProcessor ERROR: Could not put job on SSQ

Tags: adobe, render, tiff, jdf

When trying to run the Adobe PDF Print Engine (APPE) with a command like:

```
.\JDFPrintProcessor.exe -injdf "C:\Temp\PrintMyPDF.jdf" -outdir "C:\Temp\output"
```

I get the following error:

```
_________________
JDFPrintProcessor ERROR: Could not put job on SSQ.

Terminating JDF Print Processor
```

Answer (score 0):

The required format for **-injdf absolute file paths** is 'file:///...' (but not for other parameters).  E.g.

```
.\JDFPrintProcessor.exe -injdf "file:///c:/Temp/PrintMyPDF.jdf" -outdir "C:\Temp\output"
```

Correct output is:

```
>>>> Submitting J O B  0 to JDF Player <<<<<
>>>> Job 0 was received on command line
>>>> Job 0 URL is file:///c:/Temp/PrintMyPDF.jdf
[TiffFile: PrintMyPDF001_p00.tif,1,0,Cyan,5100x6600]
[TiffFile: PrintMyPDF001_p01.tif,1,1,Magenta,5100x6600]
[TiffFile: PrintMyPDF001_p02.tif,1,2,Yellow,5100x6600]
[TiffFile: PrintMyPDF001_p03.tif,1,3,Black,5100x6600]
[JobTime Job 0: PrintMyPDF, 0.652 sec.]

<<<<< Job 0 processing completed: Successful >>>>>

Terminating JDF Print Processor
```

Hope this saves someone some time (including my future self)